# Get the JSON representation of a handsontable

Tags: handsontable

The following script can make a 3x2 editable table: [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/sijesu/7/edit?html,js,output):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.8.2/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.8.2/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="example1" class="hot handsontable htRowHeaders htColumnHeaders"></div>
  <br><br>
  <div class="json-result">to print a JSON representation</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  function getData() {
    return [
      ['A1', 'B1'],
      ['A2', 'B2'],
      ['A3', 'B3']];
  }

  var
    example1 = document.getElementById('example1'),
    settings1,
    hot1;

  settings1 = {
    data: getData(),
    rowHeaders: false,
    colHeaders: false,
    contextMenu: false
  };
  hot1 = new Handsontable(example1, settings1);

});
```

After manually changing some values in the table, I would like to return a JSON value that represents the value of the cells of the table, and print it at `div` `json-result`. Does anyone know what API I could use to do so?

Comment: How do you expect the resulting JSON would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coincidentally, the function that you're looking for is called `getData`. You can use it on the `Handsontable` instance and you'll get an array of arrays, representing the current data that is in the table. From there on you can either reformat the json into whatever you like or simply `JSON.strigify` it. Here's a [working example](https://jsbin.com/fujupihabu/edit?html,js,output).